# Xamarin.Android Heap Size Control

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, heap-memory

I am developing an app but I got "Java heap space OutOfMemoryError". Is there a way to monitor current(realtime) Heap Usage on Xamarin.Android?.

Comment: Using the Memory Profiler  (from Android Studio) https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler.html

Comment: Is there an alternative for Visual Studio?

Comment: The Xamarin Profiler is available under Visual Studio Enterprise, but it does not provide a detailed view of the Java side of your app as the Android Studio's Memory Profiler does.

Comment: I will try Xamarin Profiler.

Answer (score -1):

In VS no option to monitor it

But

if you want to increase build heap size.

For visual studio 2015 right click Project --> Properties --> Android Options --> Advanced and heap size there.

and

increase Heap size of your application you can set this in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application android:largeHeap="true"></application>
```

Comment: In VS for mac its available on Project --> Properties --> Android Build

Comment: The heap size in the build options has **nothing** to do with the runtime heap of your app

Comment: @SushiHangover  according to my understanding his question contain "I am developing an app", that means he is in development mode, thats why i post this answer